# Prove if n<m there is at least one [(n/m)]?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose there are n programmers in m cubicles. Prove that there must be at least one
cubicle containing at least $\lceil \frac{n}{m} \rceil$ programmers.

Note: I was not able to find the right sign [ is returning first upper integer in case of not integer number.

```
1.1 = 2
1.5 = 2
1.9 = 2
```

Comment: $\lceil n/m \rceil$

Comment: sounds like pigeon hole principle : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: The tag ([tag:theorem-provers]) is for questions about software designed for checking formal proofs or assisting with writing them, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about proofs of theorems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove by contradiction: suppose that no cubicles have at least $\frac{n}{m}$ programmers. Then the total amount of programmers is less than $n$, a contradiction. Also, the amount in each cubicle must be an integer, which proves the slightly stronger result with the ceiling function.

Comment: You are answer is exactly right but can you prove if no cubicles have at least n/m programmers then the total amount of programmers is less than n. I can understand exactly what you mean but I can not prove it on the paper.

Comment: If no cubicles have at least n/m programmers, they all have less. There are m cubicles so the maximum total amount of programmers is m*(n/m) ( amount of terms times maximum value of a term) This simplifies to n.